# Trouble getting Elasticsearch to run

Tags: elasticsearch, java

I am trying to get Elasticsearch to run but unable to. Running ./bin/elasticsearch yields the following error:

```
Initialization Failed ...
- MissingResourceException[Can't find bundle for base name org.elasticsearch.common.joda.time.format.messages, locale en]
```

I'm running Mac OSX 10.8.2 and java -version yields:

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Any ideas on what the problem is? I also trying running the ./bin/elasticsearch.in.sh script before but nothing has worked

Comment: Try to run bin/elasticsearch -f, that might yield some more logging information, also turn up logging info by editing config/logging.yml. I would guess that a missing bundle means a file is missing.

Comment: You should accept this answer to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the file on the elasticsearch website was messed up or had a bad download. I downloaded the tar.gz version and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue with both Elasticsearch 1.7 & Elasticsearch 2.0 on Mac OSx 10.10 Yosemite. I messed around with installing Java 8's JRE without success.

I ended up installing the Java 8 JDK in addition to the JRE based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850247/installing-elasticsearch-on-osx-mavericks/22853048#22853048).

Additionally here's Elasticsearch's [instructions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup.html)