# Use specific version of Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, homebrew

I've installed Elastichsearch 1.7 via Homebrew, which is now "keg-only". I don't fully understand this, but it means that I can't run it simply using `elasticsearch` like I used to, but I still need to. My Node.js app only works with this version. Is there anything I can do to symlink it or whatever is necessary for other tools to detect it? Any help would be really appreciated.

Homebrew info:

```
elasticsearch@1.7: stable 1.7.6 [keg-only]
Distributed search & analytics engine
https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch
/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch@1.7/1.7.6_1 (38 files, 29.7M)
  Built from source on 2017-02-09 at 17:45:23
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/elasticsearch@1.7.rb
==> Requirements
Required: java >= 1.7 ✔
==> Caveats
Data:    /usr/local/var/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_ourcore/
Logs:    /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_ourcore.log
Plugins: /usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch/plugins/
Config:  /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/

This formula is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local.

This is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch@1.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc


To have launchd start elasticsearch@1.7 now and restart at login:
  brew services start elasticsearch@1.7
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  elasticsearch --config=/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch@1.7/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Elasticsearch on OSX Mavericks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22850247/installing-elasticsearch-on-osx-mavericks)